# Find resonance for vibration motor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, resonance

I have a motor that spins with a certain RPM (let's consider it constant: `r`). I attach a weight of mass `m` on a (weightless) shaft of length `l` that when spinning will generate vibration forces. Might also matter the weight of the motor body and what it's attached to, if so call it `W`.

Given this, is there any way of computing `m` and `l` to achieve resonance on that vibrating movement?

The attached weight is considered punctiform.

[image: Vibration Motor illustration]

Comment: You have stated how you will provide a periodic driving force. What is the system with its own natural frequency which you hope to make resonate using your driving force? [If you don't understand what I'm asking, please look up the definitions of *forced oscillations* and *resonance*.]

Comment: What characteristics of the system other than mass influence it's natural frequency? I'll be digging deeper into that

Comment: The short answer to your last question is *restoring force per unit displacement*. For example the natural frequency of a mass attached to a fixed point by a spring is $$f=\frac 1{2\pi}\sqrt \frac km$$ in which $k$ is the spring constant (restoring force per unit extension).  **But** you haven't said what your system *is*!  You would, I think, be helped by trying to answer the question in my comment above.